# Need to toggle only the specific paragraph

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to toggle the specific paragraph only but not both at the same time.
.popuplink is the same class for both the ul in the html code.
IDs are dynamically generated and it starts from 0 (in the end).
Example: If I click the id `promo_popup_cta_0` then `promo_popup_wrapper_0` should toggle.

When this id `promo_popup_cta_0` is with 0 in the end then this id will be `promo_popup_wrapper_0` is with 0 in the end. Below won't work if there are 100 of div with different numbers. I don't want to write separate code for separate clicks.

```js
$("#promo_popup_cta_0").on("click", function() {
  $("#promo_popup_wrapper_0").slideToggle();
});

$(".popupLink").on("click", function() {
  $(".popupContentWrapper").slideToggle();
});

$(".popupCloseBtn").on("click", function() {
  $(".popupContentWrapper").slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-top-info">

  <div class="promo-row">
    <p>
      FREE SHIPPING ON U.S. ORDERS OF $100 + 
      <u class="popupLink" id="promo_popup_cta_0">Details</u>
    </p>
    <p></p>
    <div class="popupContentWrapper" id="promo_popup_wrapper_0">
      <div class="text-right">
        <div class="popupCloseBtn">Close X</div>
      </div>
      <div class="popupContent">
        <p>Nothing says thank you, and I love you, quite like snacks, especially when they come packaged in a FEED 10 Bag. Curated with our friends at Mouth, this bundle features a delightful mix of salty and sweet</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="promo-row">
    <p>
      Navy blue bag day <u class="popupLink" id="promo_popup_cta_1">For More</u>
    </p>
    <p></p>
    <div class="popupContentWrapper" id="promo_popup_wrapper_1">
      <div class="text-right">
        <div class="popupCloseBtn">Close X</div>
      </div>
      <div class="popupContent">

        <p style="margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify;"><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">Lorem Ipsum</strong>&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
          of type and scrambled it to make a type&nbsp;</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `this` to refer to the element being clicked on, otherwise (as you discovered) you will refer to all matching elements. Use `.closest()` to traverse up the DOM and when needed, `.find()` to traverse down:

```js
$(".popupLink").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest('.promo-row').find(".popupContentWrapper").slideToggle();
});

$(".popupCloseBtn").on("click", function() {
   $(this).closest(".popupContentWrapper").slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header-top-info">

  <div class="promo-row">
    <p>
      FREE SHIPPING ON U.S. ORDERS OF $100 +
      <u class="popupLink" id="promo_popup_cta_0">Details</u>
    </p>
    <p></p>
    <div class="popupContentWrapper" id="promo_popup_wrapper_0">
      <div class="text-right">
        <div class="popupCloseBtn">Close X</div>
      </div>
      <div class="popupContent">
        <p>Nothing says thank you, and I love you, quite like snacks, especially when they come packaged in a FEED 10 Bag. Curated with our friends at Mouth, this bundle features a delightful mix of salty and sweet</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="promo-row">
    <p>
      Navy blue bag day <u class="popupLink" id="promo_popup_cta_1">For More</u>
    </p>
    <p></p>
    <div class="popupContentWrapper" id="promo_popup_wrapper_1">
      <div class="text-right">
        <div class="popupCloseBtn">Close X</div>
      </div>
      <div class="popupContent">

        <p style="margin: 0px 0px 15px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify;"><strong style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">Lorem Ipsum</strong>&nbsp;is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley
          of type and scrambled it to make a type&nbsp;</p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was very clear answer, just realised how easy it was

Answer (score 0):

If you stay consistent and the Id's are all the same besides for the number at the end you can take the number after the last `_` and use it like this

```
$(".popupLink").on("click", function(e) {
    var id = e.target.id;
    var n = id.lastIndexOf('_');
    var result = id.substring(n + 1);
    $("#promo_popup_wrapper_" + result).slideToggle();
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This looks correct but I'm not sure why it didn't work when I added in my code base.